# Select One menu is not setting the selected value to backend

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hi all I´m havig a problem trying to select a value from a selectOneMenu component. I´m using primefaces 5 and jsf 2

I have a list of objects to display in the selectOneMenu, when a object is selected a backend variable (with the same type of object )should caugth that value. But when I change the value in the selectOneMenu nothing happens I mean the setter method of the variable is not called.

this is my  selectOneMenu  code

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectRepositorio"
    value="#{cadastroDocumentoControler.repositorio}">
    <f:selectItems 
        value="#{cadastroDocumentoControler.items}"  />

     <p:ajax update="tree" event="change" /> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

this is the get method for populate a list items, and works great, I can see all the elements in the 
selectOneMenu

```
public List<SelectItem> getItems(){
            listarRepositorios();

     items.add(0, new SelectItem("", "choose one..."));


       for(IRepositorio repositorio: repositorioList){     
           SelectItem si = new SelectItem(repositorio,repositorio.getNome());             
           items.add(si);
       }
       return items;

}
```

My repositorio variable, that variable should caugth the selected value

```
private IRepositorio repositorio = EntityBeanFactory.getRepositorio();
```

The getters and setters

```
public void setRepositorio(IRepositorio repositorio) {

    this.repositorio = repositorio;
    System.out.println("valor after execute setRepositorio: "+repositorio);

}

public IRepositorio getRepositorio() {
    System.out.println("value in the method getRepositorio: "+repositorio);
    return repositorio;

}
```

The main problem is that the setter method is not called, I din´t have a converter but the converter error was not printed, but I created one, but still nothing happens

My converter

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Repositorio.class)
public class RepositorioConverter implements Converter {
 private IRepositorioDAO repositorioDAO = DAOFactory.getRepositorioDAO();


@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        String idRepositorio) {
    if (idRepositorio==null || idRepositorio.trim().length()==0) {
        return null;
    }

    return repositorioDAO.find(Integer.parseInt(idRepositorio));
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) {
    IRepositorio repositorio = (IRepositorio) value;
    Integer id = repositorio.getId();
    return id.toString();
}


}
```

And finally I have my   @ManagedBean in @SessionScoped

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you used converter, you must use list of IRepositorio instead of used list of SelectItem.
2. When using a custom converter in `p:selectOneMenu`, you should always override the equals() method of the object involved. For you, you should override equal() at the Class of repositorio. This is an example of override equal() method.

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>     if (obj == null)
>       return false;
>     if (!(obj instanceof IRepositorio))
>       return false;
>     return ((ReferenceData) obj).getCode().equals(this.code);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot the IRepositorio and the
 <p:ajax update="tree" process="@this" event="change"  /> instead  <p:ajax update="tree"  event="change"  /> solved my problem thanks a lot